# Looking for a board game

Tags: identify-this-game, board-game-adaptations

I once ran into a computer implementation of an old board game that seemed rather interesting, unfortunately I am unable to recall either. What I do remember:

Probable

- Java (advertised support for linux)
- hex tiles
- recruit squads of magical beasts for combat

Possible

- recent IOS (or Android) version, unrelated to the Java version
- hex tiles arranged in concentric "terrain" zones, the goal being to reach the center
- special (angelic/guardian) creatures with greater powers
- two modes, one for recruiting and one for combat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very much like [Titan](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/103/titan). The Java version may be [Colossus](http://colossus.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, thanks - right on both counts. Originally I considered this game too complicated (also, Colossus being Java and graphically unappealing), but since having picked up roguelikes I've become open to the idea of slower-paced games. Though, I had given up on ever finding this game again.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Slugathon](https://github.com/dripton/Slugathon/wiki) which unlike [Colossus](http://colossus.sourceforge.net/) is still active, if sporadically so. Since incomplete, Slugathon currently lacks features and is buggy, slow. The server already provides a ranking system, and the AI seems stronger than that of Colossus. That said, despite its awful UI, Colossus is the better alternative for beginning players.

Anyone else, choosing is a toss-up. I haven't tested Colossus' server (requires a web account), so I don't know if it provides rankings.